# Is the domain of $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x},x\le1$?

Tags: functions

The domain of $\sqrt x$ should be $x\ge0$, right? So the solutions on the textbook is wrong?

[image: picture 1: this is what on the textbook]
[image: picture 2: this is my answer]

Comment: Yes, the largest possible real domain is $x\le1$. But you may take the domain to be a subset of this. So the book isn't entirely wrong.

Comment: @Forester The codomain is a superset of the range.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Sorry, I messed up the terms.